# Angular application security error: Sanitizing unsafe style value

Tags: javascript, angular, security, xss

In my angular app, initially, I used `bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value: string)` and it worked but in security testing of my application, it gave error `Angular Usage of Unsafe DOM Sanitizer`.

In this [blog](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-security-the-domsanitizer-service-2202c83bd90), it's beautifully explained why not to skip sanitization and how to manually sanitize a value. But I could not figure out **how to sanitize a CSS styling manually using `SecurityContext.STYLE`**

**Error:**

> WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0,
>   0, 0, 0.7) 100%, rgb(117, 79, 182) 100%) (see
>   http://g.co/ng/security#xss)
>
> safeUrl unsafe

```js
getBgUrl(category: ICategory): SafeStyle {
  console.log('safeUrl', this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.STYLE, `linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%, rgb(117, 79, 182) 100%)`));
  // return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 30%, ${this.gradientColors[category.id % 5]} 100%), url(${category.thumbnail})`);
}
```

```html
<div class="explore-grid">
<mat-card 
  *ngFor="let category of categories"
  [style.background-image]="getBgUrl(category)"
  [routerLink]="['/Category',category.id]">
    <span>{{category.name}}</span>
</mat-card>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a limitation in the sanitizer. According to [sources](https://github.com/mprobst/angular/blob/89cb8637f04a61622e3611486d6e15727c07ffd9/modules/%40angular/platform-browser/src/security/style_sanitizer.ts) the regexp for style safety check looks like this.

```
/^([-,."'%_!# a-zA-Z0-9]+|(?:(?:matrix|translate|scale|rotate|skew|perspective)(?:X|Y|3d)?|(?:rgb|hsl)a?|(?:repeating-)?(?:linear|radial)-gradient|(?:calc|attr))\([-0-9.%, #a-zA-Z]+\))$/g
```

Which, I believe, supports either linear-gradient() or rgba() but not one nested in another. If you really need that transparency, maybe [#RRGGBBAA notation](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-rrggbbaa) can help? I tested your example with that, it works.

Comment: thanks dareka, that was helpful. i"ll look for alternatives.. and also raise an issue in their page.